# Make first letter of my taxonomy uppercase

Tags: php, taxonomy

I'm using

```
echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'trpropcity', '', ' ', '' );
```

to show a taxonomy link, I'd like to make this instance of it only have the first letter capitalized, Cleveland not CLEVELAND, I realize I could just change the taxonomy, but I actually want it all caps everywhere else on the site, so I figured it would be best to just change it once. I've been playing with ucwords and strtolower but haven't had any success yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build the links yourself:

```
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'trpropcity');
if($terms)
  foreach($terms as $term)
    echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($term, 'trpropcity').'">'.ucwords(strtolower($term->name)).'</a>';
```

Comment: @Chuck use `ucfirst` instead of `ucwords`

Comment: this worked except one small issue, if a post has no taxonomy assigned to it I get a warning, Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). My guess is I need to check if it has a taxonomy assigned to it and based on that proceed to echo. I'll have to keep working on that.

Comment: no, the issue is that a post may have no terms; use the updated code

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative way - you can just use CSS styling for taxonomy links, might work too.

```
text-transform:capitalize;
```

Comment: actually this might be a better idea than using PHP; the only downside is that search engines see the caps

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to only work if starting with lowercase to begin with, cleveland to Cleveland but not CLEVELAND to Cleveland.

Answer (score 3):

More of a php question but i use [**ucfirst**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.ucfirst.php)